# getting error for a table which I did not create using Entity Framwork Code first approach. error is invalid object name "XXXX"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

Initial migration code is below where I never create `dbo.StudentEvent1` but I get error when I run my asp.net MVC application using this database.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.StudentEvents",
            c => new
                {
                    StudentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    EventId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    isAttended = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.StudentId, t.EventId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Events", t => t.EventId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Students", t => t.StudentId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.StudentId)
            .Index(t => t.EventId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TeacherEvents",
            c => new
                {
                    TeacherId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    EventId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Duties = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.TeacherId, t.EventId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Events", t => t.EventId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Teachers", t => t.TeacherId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.TeacherId)
            .Index(t => t.EventId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your package manager console and Select **Default project**

then `Enable-Migrations` is use for Enable Migrations 
then `add-migrations` is added your changes in Migrations 
then `Update-Database` is apply to database

please refer below link : `http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx`

thanks